# Getting stressed for going to gym

Tags: stress

I have been going to both Gym and Crossfit alternate days for the past 3-4 months regularly. Lately, I have started feeling stressed about going to the Gym. I feel I am missing rest after coming from work and getting ready to go to the gym\workout is seeming like a regular activity and stressing me. Is this a normal thing people undergo? Is there a good way to deal with this?

Comment: How much "me time" do you get after you go to gym? Even though I love gym, I do feel stressed / "gutted" if i have like 30 mins to myself before going to bed to start the next day. Are you have rest days? (days where you arent doing any exercise)

Comment: Really? It's the complete opposite for me, _i.e._, stress relief. What time do you go to the gym?

Answer (score 1):

Take a break.

The main question here is why do you go to the gym? Personally, I go for a bit of stress relief, because I want to get stronger, and because I enjoy the training and shooting the sh!t with the people I train with.

Saying that, I do sometimes hit periods where training seems like a chore, and when that happens, I take a week or two off.

It's important to note that I don't just sit on the sofa in my underwear and binge watch Netflix (well, maybe on the occasional Sunday...), I stop my regular training, but still do something to keep me active.

As was eluded to in the comments, getting "me" time is important, something that you can do by yourself without feeling pressure from anyone. The gym can sometimes provide this, but if you're the sort of person who's very aware of the people around you, it may feel like you have to perform at peak every time you're in the gym, so you're not judged too harshly by others (though honestly, most people very rarely care what others are doing in the gym, as long as they're not in the way, or not doing something stupid or amusing (or stupidly amusing)).

I'm a little hesitant to mention it, but it is also possible that you're over training. If you're hitting the gym and Crossfit classes on alternate days, then depending on what you do, that has the potential to be a lot of work and stress on your body. If you're not recovering fully between each session, then systemic fatigue is going to build up over time, until it hits a point where your body just needs to rest and doesn't want to train.

You can look up symptoms of over training (or, under recovering, which is usually what it is), but from memory they do include things like a lack to motivation to train. If you're lacking motivation to train, but still put on onus on yourself to hit the gym every day, then you're going to be stressing yourself out over the perceived belief that you HAVE to train every day, even when you really just don't want to.

So, to go back to my original point, take a break. Take a week off of training, that time when you're supposed to be training in the evening after work, go for a walk and listen to a podcast, or go and gently swim for an hour. Treat yourself to a spa day, take a yoga class, or even just do 30 minutes of stretching for those parts of your body that need it.

I don't know what your goals are, or why you've been hitting it so hard, but taking a week off isn't going to mean all your muscle suddenly wastes away, or that all the body fat you've lost magically appears back overnight. What it might mean is that you reignite your passion for it, and carry on making progress.

Answer (score 1):

Try and divide your workouts properly.
You are no machine. Your muscles need rest as much as they need to be worked out.

Ideally, a muscle needs rest for about 72 hrs to properly recover. But 48 hrs of a gap is also sufficient to re-train the muscle. I believe you are overstressing the muscle by working out in the gym and also Crossfiting.

30-40 Min of weights training is sufficient in the Gym if you are into CrossFit as well.

And apart from all this make fitness a lifestyle, not stress.

Answer (score 0):

Going to the gym every other day for 3-4 months is a pretty tough schedule to be honest. Hopefully you've seen some great results but that's a tough program if you've stuck with it and really given it your all.

For me the point of fitness is to be able to (a) live a long and healthy life and (b) to let me use my body for a variety of things.

You may want to consider dropping down to lifting twice a week for an hour a pop, maybe on Mondays and Fridays, and then doing some sports a few days a week. Racquetball, soccer/football, volleyball: anything that keeps you moving and is new and different.

If you lift twice a week you won't really get sore and you'll maintain your strength and maybe even bump it up a notch. It's only two hours out of your week and it frees you up to do other things.

I live in the mountains so come winter time I spend a lot of time snowboarding and my weight lifting drops to twice a week. But I have *way more fun* and come spring I didn't really lose much strength.

Comment: No (c) I love having a six-pack? lol

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to work out 5 days a week, if you're not enjoying it anymore, there's no point. Do it 3 times a week and you'll be fine. Rest on the other days.

You may need to adjust your routine (maybe full body instead of a muscle split if that's what you're doing), but it will give you more time to yourself and more time for your muscle to rebuild after you break them down. 3 lifting sessions a week is enough to be quite fit. You can also do a stretching routine to work on your mobility at home instead of going to the gym/crossfit on your off-days, it's less of hassle IMO

Also why do you go to 2 different places (with 2 different subscriptions I assume) ? Can't you do everything you want to do at one place ?

Personally, what I do is that I go to a gymnastic gym twice a week, to have access to parallel bars, rings, pommel horses, etc, and do my skill training plus a strength training session (pushups, dips, pullups, rows, handstands, deadlift), and do one session a week at home of just bodyweight strength training. I like that it's so varied, and it gives me at least a day between training sessions

Answer (score -2):

Try hit the treatmill n jog for 10-15mins.this is how i get my mood.if we moody trust me we will not finish our workout so i always hit the treatmill n jog for 15mins.try it